# can't install any nuget package in visual studio 2012. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

In a solution in Visual studio 2012, I get `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.` every time I try to install any Nuget package. I created a new project and I can install packages without issues, so there must be something in the project/solution that is missing/corrupt/invalid I guess. How can I see what exactly is causing this error?

Comment: Try the `-Verbose` switch in `Install-Package`.

Comment: I tried with `install-package -verbose jquery`. It started adding files, then it said "uninstalling jquery 2.0.3" and this ... `Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  -verbose jquery
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue was that the solution was in Source control, and I had to 'check out' the project or the package installer would not have permission to update the files. So, after checking out the project I can install packages.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: My TFS settings were "don't check out on edit" and "check out on save". I set them to "check out on edit or save" and this problem was solved!

Answer (score 3):

Delete the contents of your `packages` directory. Then update or re-install jQuery.

You may need to uninstall first using the `-force` flag.

Comment: Well, jQuery was just an example, it's happening with any package I try to install (but when I created a new project, I could install the same packages without issues). I deleted the packages folder, tried again, same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message when using Visual Studio 2017.  In my situation the problem was because someone had checked in the .vspscc and .vssscc files into TFS.  Deleting these solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue because of Resharper Build & Run Module. Just disable the "Use ReSharper Build" option from ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> Build -> General.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this (or at least a similar) problem - got the `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component` for many (but not all) references when running update-package from the NuGet command prompt. To update all references in solution with NuGet package Manager didn't work either.

The problem simply went away when updating NuGet plugin to 2.7 (from 2.2)...